# Can i use css over iframe in my web page?

Tags: css, iframe

i am trying to modify the website that i am getting in the iframe, and i get this error:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://becutan.st2" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at contents (http://becutan.st2/js/jquery-1.11.3.js:3048:60)
at Function.map (http://becutan.st2/js/jquery-1.11.3.js:503:29).

so, maybe i can modify with css ? Is css also blocked ?

Answer (score 1):

The website you're trying to display has blocked beeing displayed in an iframe.

**There's nothing you can do about that,** sorry.

Comment: i am seeing the other website in the iframe, but can not modify with css and js.

Comment: i know that there is possible communication with the iframe and parent site but i can not modify the child site script.https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: Is the website with the frame and the displayed site on the same domain?

Comment: Ok that's the issue. It's not possible to interact with cross-domain pages in frames due to security reasons.